# How do i make it so bootstrap modal goes over the scroll nav?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello guys i'm having an issue with my bootstrap template the navigator covers the modal.. how would i go about disabling scrolling so the modal can stay above it?

my issue 
http://prntscr.com/2wzx6w

sorry about the little information hit me with some examples if you need more intel.

the menu code = `

```
           <a href="http://www.jtvdev.com"><div class="logo">

           </div></a> 
              </div>
              <!-- Logo End -->
              <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
              <div class="mobile navbar-header">
                 <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href=".html">
                 <i class="icon-reorder icon-2x"></i>
                 </a> 
              </div>
              <!-- Mobile Menu End -->
              <!-- Menu Start -->
              <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse menu">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav sf-menu">

                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                 </ul>
              </nav>
              <!-- Menu End --> 
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Header End -->`
```

the modal code=

`

```
           <a href="http://www.jtvdev.com"><div class="logo">

           </div></a> 
              </div>
              <!-- Logo End -->
              <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
              <div class="mobile navbar-header">
                 <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href=".html">
                 <i class="icon-reorder icon-2x"></i>
                 </a> 
              </div>
              <!-- Mobile Menu End -->
              <!-- Menu Start -->
              <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse menu">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav sf-menu">

                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                 </ul>
              </nav>
              <!-- Menu End --> 
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Header End -->`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your problem, therefore I think it is in your css file.
If you want a quick hack, try adding this to your CSS:

```
.modal {
    z-index: 999 !important;
 }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1hl6wxvCAhefIpmOv323

Answer (score 0):

**The CSS z-index property of navigator should be less than modal. Such as -**

```
.modal {
    z-index: 777;
}

.nav{
    z-index: 77;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solution was:

```
.modal-open .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 17px;
}
```